# How to send a fixed-width text email?

Tags: python, sendmail, fixed-width

I have a python script that generates fixed width text like this:

```
            Hour|Total yyyyyyy|xxxxxx xxxxxxx|Total Inconsistencies|xxxxxxx Inconsistencies
----------------|-------------|---------------|---------------------|-----------------------
2018-12-17_15:00          1893               1          273 (14.42%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_14:00          1844               3          282 (15.29%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_13:00          1850               4          261 (14.11%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_12:00          1760               3          235 (13.35%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_11:00          1771               3          336 (18.97%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_10:00          1770               2          180 (10.17%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_09:00          1685               0           98 ( 5.82%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_08:00          1737               0          109 ( 6.28%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_07:00          1626               0          153 ( 9.41%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_06:00          1724               0          290 (16.82%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_05:00          1782               0          141 ( 7.91%)              0 ( 0.00%)
2018-12-17_04:00          1650               0           76 ( 4.61%)              0 ( 0.00%)
```

I want to send this as an email so that the text shows up as fixed with body in the email.  How can I do that?

Comment: Send HTML mail and wrap it in `<table>` or `<pre>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the content type you are getting. If the content type is "Content-Type: text/plain;" then you would be seeing it correctly. I am betting that it is "Content-Type: text/html". if you want HTML to appear exactly as the text looks, use `<pre>` and `</pre>`.

```
content = "<pre>" + content + "</pre>"
```

What I might consider a more direct approach to the problem is to send the correct header:

```
toClause + "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n" + content
```

Comment: Many email clients DO NOT (by default) display text/plain using a fixed width font.